# How to make an average from DB data? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'

Tags: python, mysql, types, casting

I'm looping through some data returned from a MySQL database. I don't have control over the data formats in the DB (or anything else related to the data).

I want to create a mean (average) of the returned values. The values look like this when a DB row is printed in Python:

```
('username', Decimal('8.4600'), Decimal('10.4300'), Decimal('9.48600000'), Decimal('1.9700'), 5L)
```

My code is basically just this:

```
import numpy
#make a list in a loop from the DB data rows
avg = numpy.mean(list)
```

My error is:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'

Obviously, I need to convert the types. I would prefer to convert DB Decimal type to a common Python type (such as float). I'm not working with money; the numbers are appropriately represented as floats.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either cast everything as float during your loop or use a list comprehension to do so. float(Decimal('10.4300')) works. If you have control over your query I don't see why you couldn't average it there either.